# How to prevent Hibernate from flushing in list?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple Hibernate query like:

```
from MyEntity where name = ?
```

Nothing fancy, but it's called many times in a fairly big transaction (lasts one second, may load dozens or hundreds of entities). Profiler shows that a lot of time is spent in:

```
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1240)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
```

In other words - flushing changes before running the actual query.

Can I somehow prevent Hibernate from doing this flush at all?

If not, what can I do to make it faster?

Comment: Do you run the query with different binding parameter? Does the query returns one result or multiple?

Comment: nMoncho - same parameter every time in this session, returns one unique result. Yes, I do use cacheable query.

Comment: Maybe read only transaction? Maybe marking whole entity as read only (don't remember how it can be made). Also once you fetch it for the first time, you know ID. Fetching by PK is cached in L1, should be smarter. Finally consider higher-level cache, like `@Cacheable` in Spring. Last but not least, try detaching that entity, Hibernate will forget about it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default hibernate flushes before issuing a query during a session (FlushMode.AUTO), and chews up lots of CPU time doing it. It is particularly painful if you have a session where many queries and updates run alternately.

If the query is likely to select back data that you have inserted/updated/deleted during the current session then you need these flushes. This *may* also be the case even if you haven't modified anything in the current transaction but are using a transaction-isolation level like read-uncommitted.

Assuming you don't want uncommitted reads, etc., there are two ways around this that I know of:

1. Select everything you'll need during the session *before* you make any modifications (ie., re-order things so that all your queries are issued before any modifications are made).
2. If you know for sure that you are selecting data that has not been modified in this session then you can explicitly set the flush-mode to something which won't trigger the flush, like this:

   ```
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery(SOME_QUERY_NAME);
   query.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
   ```

Comment: Regardless of the `FlushMode`, Hibernate will still flush if it detects you are querying a table you have changed since 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate changed its flush logic in version 3.3.

Now it will always flush, even if set to `FlushMode.MANUAL`, if it detects you are querying a table for which there are dirty entities.

Some workarounds I can think of:

- Reorder operations to not query dirty tables and set `FlushMode.COMMIT` or lower.
- Detach entities before modification and re-attach later so Hibernate doesn't know they were changed.
- Provide a custom [`AutoFlushEventListener`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/AutoFlushEventListener.html) with different behaviour. That will require some low-level fiddling and might break something else.