# JBoss app 100% CPU usage (VisualVM profiling)

Tags: java, profiling, cpu-usage, visualvm

I've been struggling with the problem of high load for several months now. The server literally stops working. It is necessary periodically to reboot it so that users can continue to work. Please tell me how to find the problem.

**CPU high load**
[Thread dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XT0FKVUVDQ1otSlU/view?usp=sharing)
[image: monitor]
[image: sampler]
[image: hot spots]


**CPU normal work**
[Thread dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XRVZ1dVdRRkxQZU0/view?usp=sharing)
[image: monitor]
[image: sampler]
[image: hot spots]

Comment: Please, specify what platform you are using (Windows/Linux/other and its version), Java version, and heap-related command line parameters (-Xmx, -Xms, -XX if any, etc).

Comment: Centos 6.9,  -Xms5496M -Xmx5496M -XX:MaxPermSize=1456M, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144

Comment: Could you also share the full thread dump ('Threads' tab/'Thread Dump' button), if possible, please?  screenshots you attached do not show any particularly suspicious activity. I just wonder if there are other threads that might be really busy to consume CPU that much.

Comment: @yegodm References to thread dumps present in the text of the question. Is duplicate link here without decoration: 1) CPU high load: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XT0FKVUVDQ1otSlU/view?usp=sharing 2) CPU normal work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XRVZ1dVdRRkxQZU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, sorry, thread-dumps are there. Please, ignore my previous comment - could not get through the links due to the company firewall.

Comment: In the high load scenario 24 of presumably 36 http-requests seems to be processing `SubjectListServiceImpl.getActiveSubjects`. How normal is that activity? Are you sure there is no bug in the client side that continuously invokes this method at a very high rate?

Comment: Another thing that probably matters - a few threads are performing auto-flush in seemingly read-only queries (Thread t@418, Thread t@365, etc). Flushing is not a cheap operation and typically may cause CPU spikes. Please, have a look at this question/answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403498/how-to-prevent-hibernate-from-flushing-in-list.

Comment: @yegodm thank you very much. We do have a long method `SubjectListServiceImpl.getActiveSubjects` although it can legitimately be called quite often. I'll try to disable the flush for it. And it seems now that I understand much better how to read a thread dump. Thank you! I will unsubscribe when I check the results.